# How much fast can a microcontroller read from IO pins?

Tags: io, usb, microcontroller, ethernet, high-speed-computing

What actually wonder is like the following. I will supply 8 bit data, 1 clock and 1 data valid signal to a microcontroller with 20 Mhz; and then want to send the data over ethernet or USB. I have doubts about this could be done by a microcontroller such as STM32F2xx or not.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  You likely want that loop written in asm and want it running from ram not flash, and want to crank the clock up on the microcontroller so it can get a few instructions at least per external clock so you can capture this data and have an if/then else, and save it somewhere.  eventually you stop polling the port and have to take that data and send it out the usb (unless you account for that in how much your arm clock rate exceeds the external incoming clock and data)

Comment: You want to send the data at 20 Mega bytes per second?!!!?!!